# Creating WINPE boot disc for IA64 architecture

Tags: sysprep, windows-pe, waik, imagex, itanium

Following the steps in the Windows Deployment Services getting started guide to create bootable media. After running `Copype.cmd ia64 c:\winpe` there is no equivalent of *etfsboot.com* in the *c:\winpe\iso\boot\* folder.

So as per http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749311%28WS.10%29.aspx I use *efisys.bin*.

I've then burnt the ISO to DVD using infrarecorder, but the target box (HP Z600/Intel Xeon) insists on attempting to boot that it is a non-system disc.

Any hints or tips appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand. You say the target box is a Xeon? So where does the IA64 come in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I've used an MDT PE boot disk for x86. According to someon with more experience of WinPE creating a PE boot disk can be "problematic". Once you've got one that works, keep hold of it.